# Calculating success rate

Tags: calculus

This may be very simple math, but I can't get my head around it.

Okay, I have $3500$ in my app, $1300$ of them did not make any interaction, I would like to know what percent of users did interact in my app.

I did $1300÷3500×100$, I get $37.14%$ as the answer. But, I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: So I guess doing `100-37.14` gives me accurate result, but there's must be a simpler way

Comment: 3500-1300=2200 _did_ interact with your app, so the percentage is $\dfrac{2200}{3500}\times 100$%=$62.85$%.

Comment: thank youu  - made my day